# calling function by value in C

Tags: c, arrays, function, pointers

I am new to C language somehow and I am trying here to call a function "func" in main function but it gives me compiling error. I tried to search for examples similar to this situation in Google but stil getting errors.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct str {
  int value;
  uint32_t ptr_next;
};

void func(int arg, char* arr[]);

int main() {
  int Arg;
  char* Arr[1];

  func(Arg, *Arr[1]);

  return 0;
}

void func(int arg, char* arr[]) {
  int list;

  struct str r;

  FILE* file = fopen(arr[1], "rb");

  do {
    list = fread(&r, sizeof(struct str), 1, file);

    if (list > 0)
      printf("%d ", r.value);

    fseek(file, r.ptr_next, 0);

  }

  while ((r.ptr_next != 0) && (list > 0));
}
```

The question is how can I call functions by value in C language?

Comment: Try ```func(Arg, Arr);```

Comment: I think I’m your original attempt you passed the character (contents) of the letter at index 1. Just pass the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

C only supports calling functions by value, calling by reference was added in C++ and uses the `&` symbol.

The value you are passing to the function is a location in memory, a pointer.  If you want to hand to the function a copy of the data at that memory location you'll need to make a copy for it.

```cpp
// Assuming that Arg and Arr are initialized.
char* Arr2[];                     // Make a storage place for the char**.
Arr2 = malloc(Arg*sizeof(char*)); // Make the right number of char*s in it
for(int e=0; e<Arg; e++) {        // For each elem in the main array: 
  Arr2[e]=malloc(sizeof(char)*strlen(Arr[e])); // Make space for the chars,
  strcpy(Arr2[e],Arr[e]);                      // And copy them.
}
```

---

## Side note

You haven't initialized `Arg` or `Arr` in main.  I suspect that you might have meant the command line parameters.

```cpp
int main(int Arg, char* Arr[])
```

Comment: The parameters to `main` are conventionally called `argc` and `argv`.